# Send RawTextureData that is around 1mb to server from client

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I'm putting together a test script that sends a variety of things to my server including an image byte array that is currently ~700k. As a result I'm getting the error :

> NetworkWriter WriteBytes: buffer is too large (699064) bytes. The maximum buffer size is 64K bytes.
>   UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkWriter:WriteBytesFull(Byte[])
>   Player_Data:CallCmdSendServerData(Byte[], Int32, Int32, String, String, Int32, Int32)
>   c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Player_Data.cs:45)

I've developed a script that sends to channel 2 of which the respective channel is set to Reliable Fragmented in NetworkManager. I'm realizing that just setting the channel doesn't make it all happen for large data chunks but some other layer of programming needs to occur to move this data, but I'm unsure as to how exactly to accomplish it. How do I go about moving data of this size from client to server? Thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;

[NetworkSettings(channel = 2, sendInterval = 1.0f)]

public class Player_Data : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Texture2D tex;
    public string type; 
    public string id;
    public int strength;
    public int hitpoints;

    private byte[] texBytes;
    private int texWidth;
    private int texHeight;


    private void Start()
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer && !isServer)
        {
            SendData(); // Convert raw texture to jpg byte array
        } 
    }

    [Client]
    void SendData()
    {
        texWidth = tex.width;
        texHeight = tex.height;
        type = "Deer";
        strength = 10;
        hitpoints = 120;

        StartCoroutine(DoSendData());
    }
    IEnumerator DoSendData()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        texBytes = tex.GetRawTextureData();

        CmdSendServerData(texBytes, texWidth, texHeight, type, id, strength, hitpoints);
    }

    [Command]
    void CmdSendServerData(byte[] texBytes, int tWidth, int tHeight, string type, string id, int strength, int hitpoints)
    {
        GameObject infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Image size : " + texBytes.Length.ToString() + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Image width : " + tWidth.ToString() + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Image height : " + tHeight.ToString() + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Animal type : " + type + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Animal strength : " + strength + "\n";
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Animal hit points : " + hitpoints + "\n";

        RpcDataReceivedConfirmation();
    }

    [ClientRpc]
    void RpcDataReceivedConfirmation()
    {
        if (isLocalPlayer)
        {
            DisplayDataOnClientScreen("CmdSendServerData Received Confirmation!");
        }   
    }

    [Client]
    void DisplayDataOnClientScreen(string data)
    {
        GameObject infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += data + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: It sucks that this restriction is imposed on UNet. This is why I use raw socket to do all my network stuff work, I don't waste my time with UNet at-all. Anyways, cut the bytes into multiple byes then send them with `NetworkServer.SendBytesToPlayer` or `NetworkConnection.SendBytes`. This should work.

Comment: @Programmer do you know of any good resources where i might be able to learn about this process?

Comment: @Programmer is using raw sockets an all-in proposition or could i use it just to send this specific data? can i still use networkmanager for most of my work?

Comment: Yes, you can use raw socket for sending large data then use normal Unity network API(eg networkmanager) for your other network stuff.